# Как запустить операцию параллельно как можно больше раз

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Делаю вот так:

```
static void Cacl()
{
    //Long work        
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
while (true)
   new Thread(Cacl).Start();
```

Но слабовато както... За 10 сек. работы запускается макс. около 1000 операций, а мне нужна намного большая производительность.

Comment: Если поделитесь своим 1000-ядерным процессором для тестирования кода, то объясню в лучшем виде.

Comment: Нужно больше fork бомб `int main(void){while(1) fork();}`

Comment: Я вас понял. И книжку обещаю почитать, но всеже не могли бы коротко прокомменировать такой вот скриншот https://yadi.sk/i/3EdHumB3fvuFC там программа фурычит до 4х лямов в секунду. Как это объяснить и как такую скорость хоть примерно достить на шарпе?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопрос. Укажите, в чем именно заключается проблем?

Comment: @beatsspam 1. Никак, там жёсткие оптимизации, недоступные для шарпа (и для ваших познаний в программировании, да и моих тоже). 2. Четыре миллиона паролей в секунду не означают четыре миллиона потоков в секунду. Один поток прекрасно справляется с большим числом вычислений. А реальное количество выполняемых одновременно потоков упрётся в количество ядер.

Comment: @beatsspam Вы еще наверняка создаете по одному потоку на каждую провреку хэша. Это ошибка. Да и количество потоков больше наличного количества ядер приводит к мультиплексированию в одном ядре вместо реального распараллеливания.

Comment: да действительно. спасибо за очень ценные комментарии

Comment: На самом деле зря заминусовали ТСа,  в этом треде довольно часто встречающаяся ошибка. Привязать один к одному поток к какой-то конкретной сущности в надежде на рост производительности.

Comment: И правда, давайте подчеркну. Многопоточность важна и полезна в том случае, когда у вас несколько параллельных логических линий выполнения. Например, вычисления и обновление UI. В случае повторяемых операций ваш bottleneck — процессор. Поэтому вам нужно ровно столько потоков, сколько ядер в вашем процессоре. Дальнейшее увеличение количества потоков приведёт к **замедлению** общей скорости, т. к. начнут сказываться потери на управление потоками и их переключение.

Comment: @Athari, обычно система позволяет исполнять очень много `Thread.Sleep(5000)` за то же самое время. Ведь, спать легко :)

Comment: @ony Однако за тысячи потоков компьютер спасибо не скажет. :) У меня при сотне процессов потоков меньше.